# Jquery add onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I am trying to add a onchange event to a normal ahref link.

Currently the code makes a form into a kind of slider with next and back - which works, not made by me.
At the end it changes the next text to calculate - which also works.

At that point I need it to add the onchange event so my other javascript file can do the math - this part isnt.

Here is what I have.

```
if($slider.find('.rhino-active').index() == ($slider.find('.rhino-item').length -2)){
                    $('.form-submit').html("Calculate");
                    $('.form-submit').attr(("onChange", "calculate();" ));
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the html of elements with class `form-submit` to a text (Calculate). And then adding an onChange attribute. But if those elements only contain text, the user can not trigger a change event.

You also have double parentheses in the attr function, you should only have one set.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
var size = $slider.find('.rhino-item').length,
    index = $slider.find('.rhino-active').index(),
    $ele = $('.form-submit');
if (index === size - 2) {
  // jQuery version >= 1.7
  $ele.on('change', calculate).html('Calculate');
  // otherwise
  $ele.change(calculate).html('Calculate');
  // use only one of them
}
```

If you could provide more info on the context you are working, the solution can be optimized. Thanks.

Comment: Didnt seam to work for me. Here is the demo from they guy that built the slider code.
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/multi-step-rhino/

Comment: Got it! Thanks
$('.form-submit').on('click', calculate).html('Calculate');

Comment: In the demo, I see that `.form-submit` is an anchor tag. Anchor tags do not have `onchange` event. You should try 'onclick' event instead. But to help without any info on context is hard for me.

Comment: Yeah fault it was the onclick see above your post for the right code. How would I get the form to submit and stay on the same page?

Comment: You should use [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) with `async: true`. By default `async` is true.